# Couldn't determine repo type for URL (gitlab + Mac)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to execute "make gen" command in my project directory, but have an error:
"Сouldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://gitlab.myproject/podspecs.git`: (): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line ... column ..."

I've been looking here and googling, but without success. Only found similar errors for pods and YAML, but they are specific.
I've checked my Podfile as well and it has source 'https://gitlab.myproject/podspecs.git', so that OK

Comment: This isn't a Git issue: Git does not have "repo types", it just has repositories. The error message itself sounds like something (whatever `make gen` is running) is trying to read a YAML file and there's a typo in it.

Comment: Probably related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126514

Comment: yes, I've seen this. But it's related with cocoa pods only

Comment: That particular one was due to "smart quotes", which could also mess with a YAML file. I'd also examine (closely, byte-by-byte, with a hexdump-style viewer) your other yaml files at and near the line and column specified. "Mapping values not allowed" means you have a dictionary-style key and/or value in a place where it's forbidden by whatever software you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is solved by adding repository with this command in terminal:

```
bundle exec pod repo add https://gitlab.myproject/podspecs.git
```

Answer (score 6):

pod repo add [name podSpecs] [URL Podspecs]

example:

```
pod repo add Specs http://igit.yycorp.com/specs.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to solve that problem using other responses.
So i have try different things. And finally i downgrade my cocoapods version. from 1.11.2 (last at this time) to 1.8.4 (which i had on another computer).
And it worked fine.

I did not try with other versions.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core cocoapods-deintegrate  cocoapods-downloader cocoapods-plugins cocoapods-search cocoapods-trunk cocoapods-try 
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue for my case by changing to SSH instead of HTTP for the source in my `Podfile`.

`source git@link.to.repo:domain/repo.git`

Comment: Did you create a token? If so, where did you specify it in the Podfile?

Answer (score -2):

لدي مشكلة وهي  in _inner_fn
validate_repo_id(arg_value)
File "C:\Users\FERRANE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils_validators    raise HFValidationError(
huggingface_hub.utils._validators.HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_namee': '../inputs/bert_base_uncased/'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).